# Duplicate entry 'groser' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, drupal

I get the following error after attempting to import a Drupal site database dump on my local server.

The import stops at the search_total table. I have looked in search_total for the word "groser" which I have found and isn't duplicated.

On the other hand I have found the word "großer" which leads me to believe that Mysql interprets the "ß" as a "s".

```
 search_total MyISAM utf8_general_ci
```

Any ideas on how to deal with this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: check the field in `search_total`, make sure it is also set to utf8?

Comment: Also, when you dumped the data, was it dumped in utf8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a known issue when exporting from an older MySQL version (5.0) to a newer one (5.1) for example. If you don't really care about having the exact same data in your search table (should be irrelevant if you're setting up a local development environment for example), you can ignore these duplicates with the -f flag.

See http://linuxadminzone.com/ignore-mysql-error-while-executing-bulk-statements/